# WM_PAINT Bitblitting multiple times?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, wm-paint, bitblit

This is for C++ - win32. Basically I've loaded an image (bmp) into a HBITMAP from a file and bitblitted it to the device context for the main window.

How would I call it again in case I want to change the image?

I've called InvalidateRectangle() and UpdateWindow() but that causes the window controls to flicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you invalidate the area (e.g. via `InvalidateRect`) and let your `WM_PAINT` handler repaint it.  Reasons why you would get flicker often are because you haven't overridden the `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler, your `WM_PAINT` handler isn't doing double-buffered painting, or you're invalidating (or repainting) an area larger than you need to.

This page might help: [Flicker-free Drawing: Techniques to eliminate flicker from your applications](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/flicker-free-drawing)